# Find most important words for k-means clustering using sklearn_pandas

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, sklearn-pandas

I am new to sklearn. I want my code to group data with k-means clustering based on a text column and some additional categorical variables. CountVectorizer transforms the text to a bag-of-words and OneHotEncoder transforms the categorical variables to sets of dummies.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans

def import_vectorizer():   
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(lowercase   = True,  
                             ngram_range = (1,1),
                             min_df      = .00005,  
                             max_df      = .01)
    return vectorizer
```

The DataFrameMapper from sklearn_pandas combines the bag-of-words with the dummy variables.

```
def get_X(df):
    mapper = DataFrameMapper(
        [
            ('text_col', import_vectorizer()),
            (['cat_col1', 'cat_col2', 'cat_col3', 'cat_col4'], OneHotEncoder())
        ]
    )
    return mapper.fit_transform(df)
```

To predict groups I run

```
df = pd.read_json(mydata.json)
X = get_X(df)
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=50)
kmeans.fit(X)
```

Now I want to see which features that are most important in predicting the groups. There are posts along the lines of

```
print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(50):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind])
```

However, this does not work in this case since

```
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

would only contain the feature names from the bag of words and not those produced by OneHotEncoder. Any help would be greatly  appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I was able to solve the problem after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653642/combining-bag-of-words-and-other-features-in-one-model-using-sklearn-and-pandas).

Modified get_X function:

```
def get_X(df):
    mapper = DataFrameMapper(
        [
        ('text_col', import_vectorizer()),
        (['cat_col1', 'cat_col2', 'cat_col3', 'cat_col4'], OneHotEncoder())
       ]
    )

    X = mapper.fit_transform(df)
    X_cols = (
            mapper.features[0][1].get_feature_names()
            + mapper.features[1][1].get_feature_names().tolist()
            )
    return X, X_cols
```

And then run the following code in the end.

```
print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
for i in range(50):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % X_cols[ind])
```